# Валидация без модели в YII

Tags: php, yii, валидация

Есть простая форма, которая шлет массив айдишнков таки образом:

```
<input id="Col_0" type="checkbox" name="Col[0]" value="1">
<input id="Col_1" type="checkbox" name="Col[1]" value="2">
```

и т.д.
Айдишники нужны не для того чтобы их в базу ложить, а значит CActiveRecord модели для них нет.
Вопрос:
 Как мне валидировать этот единственный айдишник в yii.? Мне всего лишь нужна функция, которая бы триммила, резала теги, проверяла бы тип и т.п. Неужели ради этого нужно  модель CFormModel создавать?

Comment: К тому же не могу найти в валидаторах (CValidator) YII функций типа trim, strip_tags? Меня это беспокоит.

Answer (score 1):

На [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580660/yii-cvalidator-rules-how-to-validate-outside-of-a-model) есть решение. Но в целом правильнее было бы использовать ещё модель.

Comment: В предложенном вами решении итак используется модель.

Comment: Я имел в виду скорее второй комментарий там.=) В целом, я решал похожую на вашу задачу созданием расширения. В потомок класса CSafeValidator добавляется метод validateValue() (примерно такой же, как в CUrlValidator), и затем этот потомок и используется.